# PHP - echo variable into JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, echo

I am trying to put a value within some javascript code like so:

```
<?
$page = "test";

echo ('<script id="template-download" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
<tr class="template-download{{if error}} ui-state-error{{/if}}">
    {{if error}}
        <td class="name" style="display: none;">${name}</td>
        <td class="size" style="display: none;">${sizef}</td>
.....etc...
            {{if thumbnail_url}}
                <img src="Img/');
                $page;
                echo('.jpg">
            {{/if}}
.....etc....
</script>');
?>
```

And the end value looks like this:

```
            {{if thumbnail_url}}
                <img src="Img/.jpg">
            {{/if}}
```

and it doesn't put the value? What am i missing???

David

Comment: What does the output look like?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not echoing page.

```
echo $page;
```

Comment: It's always the silly ones that are the hardest to spot, cos your brain just assumes they're correct :)

Answer (score 2):

thats because you're using single quotes so echo doesnt evaluates $vars and like Joe said, particulary $page is not being echoed